# Why InputStreamReader .read() waiting until forever

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have Android service and this service stay as `ServerSocket` and reading message from client than response them via socket connection

I start server socket port 5000 in one `Thread` then in that one i accept clients and reading messages.

My problem starts here . When i'm reading message sometimes my `.read()` function waiting until forever and i cannot read message.

What can i do?

Here my code

```
 var serverSocket: ServerSocket?=null

 fun startService() {//Where i start Android service
    val server = ClientHandler()
    Thread(server).start()
}

internal inner class ClientHandler() : Runnable { //Where i start Socket server
    override fun run() {
        try {
                serverSocket = ServerSocket(5000)

            while (true) {
                val socket: Socket = serverSocket!!.accept()
                socket.reuseAddress = true
                ServerThread(socket).start()
            }
        }catch (e: ConnectException) {
            _logEx("UnExpected connection error", e)
        }
        catch (ex: IOException) {
            _logEx("ClientHandler", ex)
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            _logEx("ServerSocketHandler ", e)
        }
    }

}

internal inner class ServerThread(socket: Socket) : Thread() {
    private var client: Socket = socket
    private val writer = PrintStream(client.getOutputStream())
    private var receiveString: String = ""
    override fun run() {
        try {
            _log("serversocket isclosed : ${serverSocket?.isClosed}")
            _log("socket isclosed : ${client.isClosed}")
            _log("Starting to read message")

            val inputStream = client.getInputStream()
            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream(2048)
            val buffer = ByteArray(2048)
            var bytesRead: Int
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)//Sometimes cannot read message and stays until forever
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    break
                }
                byteArrayOutputStream.reset()
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                receiveString = byteArrayOutputStream.toString()
                checkMessage(receiveString,writer)
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            _log("Cannot read the message. Please try again")
            val spReq = Error()
            spReq.sendErrorMsg(writer, "Cannot read the message. Please try again")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the same read method as `InputStream.read(byte[])` (and I'd assume so), this is what the JavaDoc says: "This method blocks until input data isavailable, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown." - So it keeps blocking and waits for input until the end of the stream is detected (assuming there are no exceptions).

Comment: @Thomas i'm getting messages with \n so it has end but although i stuck on method

Comment: `inputStream.read(buffer)` does not look at '\n'. It is like any other character. There is noting to read i would say.

Comment: `'\n'` is _not_ the end of file, it's just a line break.

Comment: so why my code stays on .read() @Thomas

Comment: I'd assume the client keeps the connection open and didn't end the stream so the socket at the server's end expects more input.

Comment: @Thomas Yes socket should keep open always because it's serversocket and client can connect but cannot read message. What is your sugesssion

Comment: Well, I'm no expert here but I'd say your client would either have to cut the connection (and thus the server socket could accept a new one) or it would need to send a marker that indicates the current message is done - your code would then have to look for that marker (some special byte value or sequence you select).